# What is JSE 2 validators in Struts 2?

Tags: validation, struts2

I am using Struts 2.3.16.3 and also using struts 2 validator in my code. like:

```
<validators>
   <field name="name">
      <field-validator type="required">
         <message>
            The name is required.
         </message>
      </field-validator>
   </field>

   <field name="age">
     <field-validator type="int">
         <param name="min">29</param>
         <param name="max">64</param>
         <message>
            Age must be in between 28 and 65
         </message>
      </field-validator>
   </field>
</validators>
```

i found out that my code is vulnerable to CVE-2016-0785.
So i have option of below from http://struts.apache.org/docs/s2-029.html

- Always validate incoming parameters' values when re-assigning them to
  certain Struts' tags attributes.
- Don't use %{...} syntax in tag
  attributes other than value unless you have a valid use-case.
- Alternatively upgrade to Struts 2.3.20.3, Struts 2.3.24.3 or Struts
  2.3.28

Also we are told that we should use JSE 2 validator.
I am not sure what it is? We are using above validator.
Can somebody tell me what is JSE 2 Validator? Is our validation comes under JSE 2 and if not, what can be done to convert into JSE 2 validator. 
Please also share some code for JSE 2 validation..

Comment: You don't need to use that validator, Struts2 has a similar [validator type `regex`](http://struts.apache.org/docs/regex-validator.html).

Comment: That is equivalent to JSE 2 validator. Anyway if you want to use this validator you need to integrate it to Struts2 framework, otherwise Struts2 validaten framework won't consume it.

Comment: @RomanC
We are using regex like:

<validator type="regex">
        <param name="fieldname">contactPersonFaxNo</param>
        <param name="regex">^[0-9\-\+]*$</param>
        <message>$errors.invalid,lb.catFaxNo</message>
</validator>

Is this equivalent to JSE 2 validator?
Also do we have to have validator for all the field sending as input parameter?
Can u send me example JSE 2 validator?

Comment: No, it would be off-topic.

Comment: ok. 
is the code snippet in comments uses the JSE 2 validator?

Comment: No, it's just Struts2 validator.

Comment: How can i convert my code to JSE 2 validator?
Can you share some link showing JSE 2 validator?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Thing is as i said our code is vulnerable to CVE-2016-0785. It is said that if we are using JSE 2 validator then it won't be issue.
But we are using above validator i.e. struts validator as u mentioned.
So i need to change my code to JSE 2 validator to avoid this vulnerablity. Thats why i am asking u to tell how can i use JSE 2 Validator in my code.

Comment: @Hitesh Where are you getting information about this "JSE 2 Validator"?

Comment: @Hitesh You have multiple options to avoid the vulnerability, they're listed. Do you even know if your code uses the vulnerable functionality?

Comment: How can i avoid vulnerability without changing much of the code?
Available options are mentioned in question.

Answer (score 0):

### JSE2 Validator means Java 2 Platform SE validation.

Package `javax.xml.validation` Description

This package provides an API for validation of XML documents. Validation is the process of verifying that an XML document is an instance of a specified XML schema. An XML schema defines the content model (also called a grammar or vocabulary) that its instance documents will represent.

There are a number of popular technologies available for creating an XML schema. Some of the most popular include:

1. Document Type Definition (DTD)
2. XML's built-in schema language.
3. W3C XML Schema (WXS) - an object-oriented XML schema language. WXS also provides a type system for constraining the character data of an XML document. WXS is maintained by the World Wide Web Consortium (W3C) and is a W3C Recommendation (that is, a ratified W3C standard specification).
4. RELAX NG (RNG) - a pattern-based, user-friendly XML schema language. RNG schemas may also use types to constrain XML character data. RNG is maintained by the Organization for the Advancement of Structured Information Standards (OASIS) and is both an OASIS and an ISO (International Organization for Standardization) standard.
5. Schematron - a rules-based XML schema language. Whereas DTD, WXS, and RNG are designed to express the structure of a content model, Schematron is designed to enforce individual rules that are difficult or impossible to express with other schema languages. Schematron is intended to supplement a schema written in structural schema language such as the aforementioned. Schematron is in the process of becoming an ISO standard.

Previous versions of JAXP supported validation as a feature of an XML parser, represented by either a **SAXParser** or **DocumentBuilder** instance.

The JAXP validation API decouples the validation of an instance document from the parsing of an XML document. This is advantageous for several reasons, some of which are:

**Support for additional schema langauges.** As of JDK 1.5, the two most popular JAXP parser implementations, Crimson and Xerces, only support a subset of the available XML schema languages. The Validation API provides a standard mechanism through which applications may take of advantage of specialization validation libraries which support additional schema languages.

**Easy runtime coupling of an XML instance and schema.** Specifying the location of a schema to use for validation with JAXP parsers can be confusing. The Validation API makes this process simple (see example below).

Usage example. The following example demonstrates validating an XML document with the Validation API (for readability, some exception handling is not shown):

```
 // parse an XML document into a DOM tree
 DocumentBuilder parser = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
 Document document = parser.parse(new File("instance.xml"));

 // create a SchemaFactory capable of understanding WXS schemas
 SchemaFactory factory =   SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);

 // load a WXS schema, represented by a Schema instance
 Source schemaFile = new StreamSource(new File("mySchema.xsd"));
 Schema schema = factory.newSchema(schemaFile);

 // create a Validator instance, which can be used to validate an instance document
 Validator validator = schema.newValidator();

 // validate the DOM tree
 try {
    validator.validate(new DOMSource(document));
 } catch (SAXException e) {
    // instance document is invalid!
 }
```

The JAXP parsing API has been integrated with the Validation API. Applications may create a Schema with the validation API and associate it with a DocumentBuilderFactory or a SAXParserFactory instance by using the DocumentBuilderFactory.setSchema(Schema) and SAXParserFactory.setSchema(Schema) methods. You should not both set a schema and call setValidating(true) on a parser factory. The former technique will cause parsers to use the new validation API; the latter will cause parsers to use their own internal validation facilities